# Добавить префикс для команд bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, .bashrc

Написал простой скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
prefix="$1 "
while true
do
    echo -ne "┌──| \e[1;36m$(hostname)\e[m [$(date +%H:%M:%S)] $(pwd) |\n└──● \e[1;36m$prefix\e[m"
    read command || exit
    case $command in
      "off")
        prefix=""
      ;;
      "on")
        read -p "Entry prefix: " prefix
        prefix="$prefix "
      ;;
      "exit")
        exit
      ;;
      *)
        $prefix $command
      ;;
      esac
done
```

Его суть в том, что он берет первый аргумент при запуске и добавляет его в начало ко всем командам. Также можно указать новый префикс используя встроенную "команду" on.

Подскажите как можно реализовать такой или похожий функционал в консоли(bash), т.е. не внутри скрипта а сразу при открытии терминала, не перенося скрипт в bashrc, я не хочу терять интерактивности консоли(хоткеи).

Comment: Вы хотите кастомную команду для терминала что ли сделать?

Comment: складывается впечатление, что ты хочешь просто `$PS1` установить, не?

Comment: есть возможность

Comment: есть возможность изменить вводимые команды, т.е. задать какой-то префикс, который будет подставлятся ко всем командам, пример: prefix ls, а после этого команда /root - покажет содержимое директории root, или prefix systemctl status, команда sshd - покажет статус sshd